# Min DateTime on Entity Framework can return null, so I'm using DateTime? to hold value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Basically I have the following statement failing:

```
DateTime? mindate = db.Table.Min(x=>x.DateCreated && x.NonZeroValue == 0);
```

This is because EF6 is trying to serialize a DBNull -> DateTime instead of DateTime?.

I also tried specifying the type explicitly on the Min:

```
DateTime? mindate = db.Table.Min<DateTime?>(x=>x.DateCreated && x.NonZeroValue == 0);
```

However, this fails as well...

So... how does one get a min datetime value using EF6?

Comment: what is the datatype of DateCreated ?

Comment: Just checked and confirmed: DateCreated is DateTime.

Comment: Then why used like a boolean in expression?

Comment: `DateTime.MinValue` is usually used when you have a non-nullable DateTime. Your DateTime is nullable so I expect (maybe) you want something like `DateTime? mindate = record.NonZeroValue == 0 ? null : record.DateCreated;`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DateTime? mindate = db.Table
    .Where(x => x.DateCreated != null && x.NonZeroValue == 0)
    .Select(x => x.DateCreated)
    .OrderBy(d => d)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```